# How to find time take by whole test suite to complete in Pytest

Tags: python, pytest

I want to know how much time has been taken by the whole test suite to complete the execution. How can I get it in Pytest framework. I can get the each test case execution result using `pytest <filename> --durations=0` cmd. But, How to get whole suite execution time>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `pytest-sugar`

`pip install pytest-sugar`

Run your tests after it,

You could something like `Results (10.00s)` after finishing the tests

Comment: Thank you. I am able to get it. But, How can I get each suite execution time separately. Let's say, I have three suite, test_a, test_b and test_c. I want to get each suite execution time instead on whole Results.

Comment: In that case, you should use something like `pytest --durations=3`

https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/example/simple.html#profiling-test-duration

Comment: If you need to get a list of the slowest 3 test durations:

`pytest --durations=3`

By default, pytest will not show test durations that are too small (<0.01s) unless -vv is passed on the command-line.

Comment: pytest --duratoions=3 will list slowest 3 test cases / durations. But, I want to get time taken to execute the each suite.

Comment: Like : test_a (0.04) , test-b (0.0.6) , test_c(0.05) when I execute all together.

Comment: I am not sure whether the pytest has that kind of library. The other thing you can do is to check each test's execution time by
`
Suppose you have 100 test and need to check each one's execution time, run `pytest test/path --duration=100`
So changing number of duration to your number of tests will solve the issue I think
`
This is a tricky way to do it so.

Comment: Okay. Thanks for the info Nithin Mohan . :)

Comment: Hi, Nithin Mohan. Do you have any idea about how to do Integration testing with pytest?. Can you suggest me some websites to learn?

Comment: It depends upon what u mean by the integration test. If you are not familiar with database integration/mocking and other things on tests, check pytest official documentation https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/contents.html  and check this tutorial also https://djangostars.com/blog/django-pytest-testing/. These might help you for better understanding

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209438/discussion-between-nithin-mohan-and-vidya).

Answer (score 1):

Although this isn't a `PyTest` solution...

You can probably make your own timer!
Here's one I made a little while ago:

```py
from time import time as t

class Timer:

    def __init__(self) : self.tstart, self.tend = None, None

    def start(self) : self.tstart = t()
    def end(self) : self.tend = t()
    def getDis(self) : return self.tend - self.tstart
```

You can use it like this:

```py
    n = Timer()
    n.start()

    # something you want to do

    n.end()

    print (n.getDis()) # gets the distance between the start and finish
```

It can print out `0.00` when measuring something really fast, like a few `import` statements, though.